# Converting a model with lots of planes to solid

Tags: mesh

I bought a model, it's exactly what I need (a massive mining facility) but on closer inspection it's 50% made of planes, even girders. I need to use this with back face culling. I turned it on in blender to see how bad it is, and about 40% of the model disappeared.

I'm getting a good enough result in using solidify with default options, 1cm thick seems to be fairly unobtrusive. Ok, so easy, just click on objects and add the modifier once at a time. But, the whole site has 20,000 objects, every stair tread and bolt is an object. At that rate it's almost easier to recreate the whole model from scratch.

I multi-selected 10 stairs, hit solidify and only the first one is affected. I'm sure there is a better way of doing this but I don't know what it is. My blender is stock 3.0.0 no plugins.

Comment: You could write a python script to add the modifier to all meshes. There are some other answers here in the Blender Stack Exchange showing how to add a modifier to all meshes. For example this one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/86262/118

Comment: Another approach you may want to investigate is to "Recalculate Normals". This could maybe fix the back face culling issue. Check for example this video for an explanation: https://youtu.be/7sK2pDByXOE --> Also this approach you probably need to write a python script to execute the "Recalculate Normals" for each mesh.

Comment: @OldChippy I didn't understand why you need Planes to Solidify (especially Bolts), can you attach a screen? Anyway ... Select all objects with one object Active (bright orange) add modifier, search for Copy Modifiers to Selected ... If you need to share some modifier parametr - right click above and choose  Copy to Selected. ... For Back Faces- yes, check the Face Normal Orientation.

Comment: Hi guys, the problem is not the normals. This is to be rendered within unreal engine. It'll only render one side of planes, and for things like vertical girders where all sides are visible then I can't just flip the face.This is the model I'm working with. 2 million polygons,20 collections consisting of 20,000 individual objects. Python script might be viable I'll have a poke around with the python example provided. I'll try the full 20,000 objects first. Adding 1cm to everything might not cause problems, otherwise I'll have to check the object types before applying it. Kind thanks!

Comment: @vklidu Excellent suggestion. Out of the box the code solution whe told to apply solidify instead decided all objects it processed. I have a long histoory in coding and I was about to dig in to the object model... but that would defocus me from my goal. I tried your solution and it worked great. It still means a whole bunch of work for me, but at least I can be selective about what gets the treatment. Some of the planes just won't better and need normals facing the right way so I can just hand pick everything that needs to be see from both sides. Kind thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @OldChippy If you expect more help please share just a part of problematic part of your model to see issue ... solving it by solidify doesnt sound good :) especially for heavy scene you double data. If you say a lot of planes ... speaking in terms of imported model, it can be just you need to Merge vertices by Distance ... or something else trivial. Without sample I still just guessing what is going on. With sample we could probably already solve your issue.